# Android ActionBar is not displaying icons

Tags: android

I'm having troubles with the ActionBar of my application, the problem is that is still showing the old android menu. I have checked other awnsers to this question but nothing has worked. Mi minimum app SDK allowed is 7 but I'm running in a device with Android 4.2.

I imported

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

This is my onCreate() method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    inputTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);
    outputTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputText);
    inputTextView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            showMessage((View) textView);
            return true;
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(inputTextView);
}
```

This is my onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

This is my XML

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_cab_done_holo_dark"
    >

</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/lol"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_go">
</item>
```

Here is my appManifest.xml, I know that it miss the package (I removed it and I'm trying to add it)

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>


<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.ricardo.message.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post your `<uses-sdk>` element from your manifest.

Comment: I'm assuming you are extending ActionBarActivity and not just imported it, correct?

Comment: Yes, I have extended it

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Per the [Adding Action Items guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems), you must use the `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` schema version of `showAsAction`, rather than `android:showAsAction`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_cab_done_holo_dark" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/lol"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_go" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

OR

Make a XML layout call the tool_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Now in you main activity add this line

```
 <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this **xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"**

Try this code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- Adds an item to the list. -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_add"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>

</menu>
```