# why does the search icon not appear on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

i know this has been asked many times. i've gone through most of the questions here regarding the above problem. but they didn't really  help. i can't find the problem in my code. so here is my code

```
package com.example.actionbaractivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

now manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.actionbaractivity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and now the menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="always|withText"/>

</menu>
```

and finally the string xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">ActionbarActivity</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_search"></string>

</resources>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android ActionBar is not displaying icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084125/android-actionbar-is-not-displaying-icons)

Comment: already seen/done that one. didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do in this way:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

then in your Activity class:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

       if(null!=searchManager ) 
       {   
         searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
       }

       searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

        return true;
    }
```

Read more about how [to add Search functionality to android App](https://developer.android.com/training/search/index.html)

Comment: i did that but got a nullpointerexception on:           searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));                                                        sorry couldn't paste the whole log here..

Comment: I think your searchview is null.make sure you have referenced it correctly