# Can't add action buttons on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to add an ActionButton on the ActionBar, but it is placed on the overflow. What i'm doing wrong?
below is a code file and the main class
///--main_activity_actions.xml--///

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action buton -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
android:title="@string/action_search"
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
android:title="@string/action_settings"
android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

//--MainActivity.java--//
    package com.example.my_first;

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater =getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void openSettings() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void openSearch() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void sendMessage(View view){
    //Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

If you want an action to have its own icon on the ActionBar, try changing

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

to

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

Comment: Given that you're using ActionBarActivity, try the solution provided by @cheeseburger. It seems to have solved similar problems for other people.

Answer (score 1):

Add this schema to your menu resource:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
```

Then change the showAsAction attribute:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
  android:title="@string/action_search"
  app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Took me days to figure that out. Answer was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084125/android-actionbar-is-not-displaying-icons).